# Unable to create registration information for file named?

Tags: c++, activex, atl

I'm trying to deploy my ActiveX Control DLL developed in ATL project in VS2008 (I'm new to this kind of deployment).

Follow some tutorials, I'm trying to create msi file for my control using Setup Project in VS2008. I've set the Register property of Primary Output to vsdrpCOM. It built with no errors, but I got the warning: Unable to create registration information for file named. Although I can install the control in IE, it doesn't work but displayed with a red X icon. I've also tried other Register options but it's no use.

I think my control is still not registered during installation because of the warning.
 Could anyone please give me some instruction to solve this? I've spent hours on google :-(

Thank you!

Comment: I'm think about another problem may make my control unusable is missing some system libraries in my installation file.
Because I've installed VS2008 which includes all necessary libraries (for example, mfc libraries,...), my control works fine. But it won't work on another machine which doesn't have these libraries.
Does this make sense? If so, which libraries should I package with the installation file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the property **vsdrfCOMSelfReg**.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h793hc1y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.